# Rubymine fails to find correct object type and report "unresolved variable" error

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, durandal, rubymine

I just upgrade the rubymine to 7.1 and it starts to reports "unresolved variable" error to the object(type: any) array.
For example in the follow typescript program:

```
public reorderedItems = ko.observableArray<any>(null);
public internalItems:KnockoutComputed<any[]>;
public itemNameExtractor:(item:any)=>string;

private whenAttached = Q.defer<any>();
private adapter:IDraggableItemListSettings;

public activate(settings:{
    adapter:IDraggableItemListSettings
}) {
    super.activate(settings);

    this.adapter = settings.adapter;

    this.selectedItems = this.adapter.selectedItems || ko.observableArray([]);
    this.internalItems = ko.computed(()=> {
        var originalSelectedItems = this.selectedItems();
        var reorderedItems = this.reorderedItems();

        originalSelectedItems.forEach(item=> {
            var itemNotInReordered = reorderedItems.filter(t=>t.item === item).length === 0;
            if (itemNotInReordered) {
                var lstItem = {
                    item: item,
                    selected: ko.observable(true)
                };

                reorderedItems.push(lstItem);
                lstItem.selected.subscribe(this.selectionChanging.bind(this));
            }
        });

        return reorderedItems;
    });
...
this.reorderedItems(items);
```

Initially, I defined `reorderedItems` and then pass `items` from parent directly into `recorderedItems`, the `items` is an object array, each `item` is `{id:xxx, item:xxx}`. But it seems rubymine cannot find `reorderedItems()` type and report `unresolved variable item` for the `t.item`

How to disable such wrong error report in rubymine?

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I can compile and run my code without any issue. Even though rubymine report the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `public` in `public reorderedItems` I am assuming you are using a class.

So you need a `this` here : `reorderedItems.filter` so `this.reorderedItems.filter`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I can run the code without any issue. I think it is not an actual error. Also, I've updated the code.

Comment: It looks like a rubymine *bug* i.e. not something I can recommend a solution for other than saying : report it to their issue tracker